# GPO to set DFS Path to Active in Referral List for mapped drive

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, dfs, mappeddrive

I have a DFS Namespace of `domain.lcl\DFS` that replicates a folder `ReplFolder` across 3 geographically dispersed servers:

```
\\VANCOUVER\FolderA
\\MADRID\FolderA
\\TOKYO\FolderA
```

I can manually map a drive to `\\domain.lcl\DFS\ReplFolder` and it works great.

However, I want to be able to set up a GPO to set the active path so that the users in Vancouver, their active path is set to `\\VANCOUVER\FolderA`, and same for the users in the other 2 locations. Is there a GPO or Registry setting that would be able to set this?

This can already be manually done by right clicking the drive letter on the client, selecting the DFS tab, and setting the preferred Path to "Active". But for 500+ users, I'd like to automate this somehow.

Unfortunately we do not have the capability to configure AD Sites & Services in our environment (it is hosted by another organization), otherwise I would go that route.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: AD Sites & Services is a core "component" of AD. It's always "enabled". You may not have it configured with your sites and subnets but it's never not "enabled". Why don't you take the time to configure it?

Comment: Yes, apologies, you are correct. It is not "configured" and we go through another organization that manages our AD who tell us they can't because of how their subnetting is set up. I've updated the question to reflect that, thanks for the clarifying comment.

Answer (score 2):

DFS clients rely on ADS&S configuration to locate the "nearest" available copy of a DFS share.
Also, the same approach is used to locate the "nearest" Domain Controller(s).
You definitely should get it configured properly.
It's crucial to proper AD operation in a multi-site environment.